# Apache2: Change response headers

Tags: http-headers, apache2, apache2-module

I'm running on my ubuntu 12.04 system apache2 and playing around with response headers. I want to change the behavior of http response headers, especially the Content-Length header. I've tried adding following lines in my apache2.conf in the IfModule mod_headers.c section:


`Header set Static-Header "Static Content with nonsense"

Header set Content-Length "1338"`



If I run *curl -I localhost* I get the expected header field *Content-Length: 1338* (curl -I performs a HEAD request).

If I run *curl -i* the Content-Length is correctly calculated.

In RFC2616, section 9.4 is described that the HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. 

Can someone explain me this behavior?!

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 always calculates the content-length from scratch when it actually does deliver content. You'll experience that same behavior if you change that header using PHP. This is necessary to make sure the Content-Length matches the length of the content that is sent after the server applied, for example, compression (if mod_deflate is active).

Because of this, in any request that sends content, your change to that header is nullified. But as Apache doesn't even look at the content in an head-request (only it's metadata), it does not calculate content-length. This is valid, as HEAD-requests don't have any body, so content-length is always zero.

Therefore, you should:
a) not modify the content-length header in the first place
b) not send one for HEAD requests

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'not modify the content-length header in the first place'? Do you mean I should generally not modify the Content-Length header?
I've tried to change the Server header just to see if it works, but it has although no effect.
Is it possible to change existing http response headers (I don't want to discuss why this would make sense)?

Comment: Exactly what I meant, yes. The webserver should be able to calculate the content-length on it's own. And for content-length, Apache (not sure for other software, might behave differently) always DOES (because it's crucial for HTTP transmissions that the header matches the size of the body that is sent, especially with chunked encoding), so you simply cannot overwrite that specific header.